# Performance difference between new MyFragment() and MyFragment.newInstance()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, singleton, fragment

In my project , I am implementing some Fragments and creating their object by using `new MyFragments()`.Some of my fragments initiated only once(Singleton).Should I use `MyFragment.newInstance()` for those fragments in place of `new MyFragments()` which are used only once ? This kind of approach will improve some performance of app ? or should I stay with my old approach `new MyFragments()` . **Here performance is my main concern.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use MyFragment.newInstance() to initiate fragments something like this:

```
OfferSingleFragment.newInstance(str);
```

And in OfferSingleFragment use:

```
    public static OfferSingleFragment newInstance(String s) {
    OfferSingleFragment f =  new OfferSingleFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("name",s);
        f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

And Later:

```
 String  str_title = getArguments().getString("name") ;
```

Because The only benefit in using the newInstance method that I see are the following :

You will have a single place where all the arguments used by the fragment could be bundled up and you don't have to write the code below everytime you instantiate a fragment(As Above).

Its a good way to tell other classes what arguments it expects to work faithfully(though you should be able to handle cases if no arguments are bundled in the fragment instance).

So, my take is that using the newInstance static method to instantiate a fragment is a good practice.

Comment: I have repiled: the newInstance static method to instantiate a fragment is a good practice.. this describes that newInstance() performs better than empty consturctor.

Comment: for more info check this link: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: I don't have any args passing through my fragment , and in Fragments I must have empty constructor (according android docs).So if I am using a fragment where I don't have arguments, than why newInstance way is a better way  ? I think this is more overhead. In this case what do you  think should I use this ?

Comment: You can use newInstance either empty constructor or with constructor it will not create any problem man!!!!!